# python multithreading is faster than sequential code ... why?

Tags: python, multithreading

In many stack overflow Q&A about python multi-threading, I read that python has GIL so multi-threading is slower than sequential code.

But in my code it doesn't look like

This is multi-threading code
code updated **02-21-2023**

```
import threading
import time

global_v = 0
thread_lock = threading.Lock()


def thread_test(num):
    thread_lock.acquire()
    global global_v
    for _ in range(num):
        global_v += 1
    thread_lock.release()


# thread run
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(9_000_000,))
thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(9_000_000,))
thread_3 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(9_000_000,))
thread_4 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(9_000_000,))
thread_5 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(9_000_000,))

thread_start = time.perf_counter()
# start thread
thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()
thread_3.start()
thread_4.start()
thread_5.start()
thread_end = time.perf_counter()

thread_1.join()
thread_2.join()
thread_3.join()
thread_4.join()
thread_5.join()
print(f"multithread run takes {thread_end-thread_start:.5f} sec")


# nomal run (sequential code)
def increment():
    global nomal_result

    for _ in range(45_000_000):
        nomal_result += 1


nomal_result = 0

start_time = time.perf_counter()
increment()
end_time = time.perf_counter()

print(f"nomal run takes {end_time-start_time:.5f} sec")
```

The result is

```
multithread run takes 0.21226 sec
nomal run takes 2.09347 sec
```

Consequently my question is this

**Q1. Why threading is faster than sequential code in python?**

**Q2. What is the different between multi-threading with lock and sequential code (I think if using a lock, the code works like sequential codes with blocking)**

Please let me know !

thanks you

**python version 3.8.10**

ps. I move my 3rd question [Python multi-threading with lock is much faster why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75516141/python-multi-threading-with-lock-is-much-faster-why)

Comment: You only measure the time to start the threads, not the time they need to complete. Join all threads and then take end time.

Comment: @MichaelButscher that ^ and you should use `perf_counter` for measurements, not `time`

Comment: Regarding Q2 there isn't much difference except that the multithreading approach has some overhead for managing threads and lock.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks to your answer but I already use lock so I think it doesn't need to join all thread because of the lock last thread end mean total thread end.

Comment: @Gameplay I tried but still multi thread is fast..
`multithread run takes 0.12414 sec
nomal run takes 0.29267 sec
`

Comment: @MichaelButscher is right about the `join` imho. Locking is a safety mechanism introduced in order not to mess up the common data. It doesn't guarantee the job being done by thread from what I remember.

Comment: But just in case I will edit my code

Comment: You can't be sure which is really the last thread running. One thread runs, holding the lock, others waiting and then some of the others run and so on but the order is not defined.

Comment: What Python version / implementation are you using?

Comment: @KellyBundy My python version is 3.8.10

Comment: @KellyBundy And IDE is pycharm

Comment: Like Louis, I believe it's because of local vs global variables. I asked for version because global variables were sped up in recent versions. I see you commented that that's apparently not it. Maybe. Would be good to see a clean version of that, in a question. There's now so much stuff in the question and the additional stuff is in a comment, that I'm not convinced of what you actually did.

Comment: @KellyBundy Thanks your comment I changed my question stuff code. 
And according to your advice I splitted my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is caused by the way CPython treats globals. This sequential version is faster than your concurrent one using CPython 3.11 on my machine:

```py
def increment():
    nomal_result = 0

    for _ in range(5_000_000):
        nomal_result += 1


nomal_result = 0

start_time = time.perf_counter()
increment()
end_time = time.perf_counter()

print(f"nomal run takes {end_time-start_time:.5f} sec")
```

Your multithreaded code is thus not faster than your sequential one. The performance gap is likely due to different CPython optimizations between the two versions and it's mostly irrelevant.

The GIL does not prevent *all* code to be efficiently multithreaded. Here is a simple counter-example:

```py
import threading
import time


def thread_test():
    time.sleep(1.0)


thread_start = time.perf_counter()

thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test)
thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test)

thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()

thread_1.join()
thread_2.join()

thread_end = time.perf_counter()

print(f"Task duration: {thread_end - thread_start:.5f} sec")
```

compared to:

```py
import time


def thread_test():
    time.sleep(1.0)


thread_start = time.perf_counter()
thread_test()
thread_test()
thread_end = time.perf_counter()

print(f"Task duration: {thread_end - thread_start:.5f} sec")
```

The multithreaded version only takes 1 second while the sequential one takes 2 seconds.

As a general rule, code that heavily call C functions and release the GIL (like as NumPy) and code that is IO-bound (network calls) will benefit from multithreading in Python. On the contrary, CPU-bound tasks such as your code won't benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks your answer and the GIL test code is really helpful for me! .
but first one It is hard to understand. After check your answer, I tried your code and doubled my count range (ex 5_000_000 to 10_000_000 and each thread 1_000_000 to 2_000_000).
Even using global value in sequential code the time gap has widen.
`thread_1 end
global_v is 2000000
thread_2 end
global_v is 4000000
thread_3 end
global_v is 6000000
thread_4 end
global_v is 8000000
thread_5 end
global_v is 10000000
multithread run takes 0.15032 sec
nomal run takes 0.49261 sec`

Comment: The gap has widen but it has done so *proportionally*. In both cases, the sequential version is approximately 3 times faster. trying with a 10x range should yield the same proportion.

Comment: After changed 3x range multi-thread performance time is similar with before.
Only sequential code's performance time has been risen. 
I updated code.

Comment: You forgot to place `thread_end = time.perf_counter()` *after* joining all threads.

Comment: I added details in my answers. The sequential code is now faster than the concurrent one because the variable `nomal_result` is now a local variable. In your very first sequential code, `normal_result` was defined at the file top-level, thus it was a global variable.