# Python multi-threading with lock is much faster why?

Tags: python, multithreading

When I compared multi-threading and sequential code.

I found some curious result.

when I use the lock, I thought it must be slower than code which is not uesd lock.

but the result is totally opposite.

I can't understand why this happen

lock make thread works like sequential code and it work blocking

but why it is fast??

```
import concurrent.futures
import threading
import time

global_v = 0
thread_lock = threading.Lock()

def thread_test(num, index):
    thread_lock.acquire()
    global global_v
    for _ in range(num):
        global_v += 1
    print(f"thread_{index} end")
    print(f"global_v is {global_v}")
    thread_lock.release()


# make thread fool
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(3000000, 1))
thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(3000000, 2))
thread_3 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(3000000, 3))
thread_4 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(3000000, 4))
thread_5 = threading.Thread(target=thread_test, args=(3000000, 5))

thread_start = time.perf_counter()
# start thread
thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()
thread_3.start()
thread_4.start()
thread_5.start()
thread_end = time.perf_counter()

thread_1.join()
thread_2.join()
thread_3.join()
thread_4.join()
thread_5.join()
print(f"multithread run takes {thread_end-thread_start:.5f} sec")
```

result is

```
thread_1 end
global_v is 3000000
thread_2 end
global_v is 6000000
thread_3 end
global_v is 9000000
thread_4 end
global_v is 12000000
thread_5 end
global_v is 15000000
**multithread run takes 0.17747 sec
nomal run takes 0.74546 sec**
```

but when I removed lock in my function

```
def thread_test(num, index):
    global global_v
    for _ in range(num):
        global_v += 1
    print(f"thread_{index} end")
    print(f"global_v is {global_v}")
```

reusult is

```
thread_2 end
global_v is 5236595thread_1 end
global_v is 5762469

thread_3 end
global_v is 5877262
thread_4 end
global_v is 7283706thread_5 end

global_v is 7396837
**multithread run takes 0.44276 sec
nomal run takes 0.69838 sec**
```

[python multithreading is faster than sequential code ... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75508198/python-multithreading-is-faster-than-sequential-code-why)

It is my before question.. my question is too long so I splited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing of the concurrent execution is wrong, `thread_end = time.perf_counter()` should be placed *after* joining the threads.

As in your previous question and after correcting the program, the remaining timing differences are due to how CPython treats and optimizes global vs. local variables. It looks like global variables are slower, thus avoid using them as much as possible and encapsulate your code into functions.

Here is a correct program you can play with to experiment with concurrency:

```py
import threading
import time

N_ITER = 50_000_000
N_THREAD = 10

assert (
    N_ITER % N_THREAD == 0
), f"N_ITER ({N_ITER}) should be a multiple of N_THREAD ({N_THREAD})"


def concurrent_execution():
    count_concurrent = 0
    lock = threading.Lock()

    def increment_concurrent(value: int):
        nonlocal count_concurrent

        with lock:
            for _ in range(value):
                count_concurrent += 1

    threads = [
        threading.Thread(target=increment_concurrent, args=(N_ITER // N_THREAD,))
        for _ in range(N_THREAD)
    ]

    start = time.perf_counter()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start

    print(f"Concurrent execution time: {elapsed:.5f} sec, count: {count_concurrent}")


def sequential_execution():
    def increment_sequential() -> int:
        count_sequential = 0

        for _ in range(N_ITER):
            count_sequential += 1

        return count_sequential

    start = time.perf_counter()
    count_sequential = increment_sequential()
    elapsed = time.perf_counter() - start

    print(f"Sequential execution time: {elapsed:.5f} sec, count: {count_sequential}")


def main():
    concurrent_execution()
    sequential_execution()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's no proper comparison, either, since now you've given the sequential one the faster variable kind.

Comment: On the contrary, it would be unfair for the sequential version to use a feature it does to need in the same way the sequential code does not uses a lock since it is not required for it to work correctly. In the end, it's up to the OP to define what to benchmark and there is no unique answer, thus your suggestion is also valid. However, on my computer the sequential version is still faster than the concurrent one using global variables for both.

Comment: I agree what you're doing might be more realistic, but the question is about threaded vs non-threaded, and your difference in variable kind overshadows that. Also, I think the threads don't need to use a global variable, either, so it's just as unfair to them, by your own argument.

Comment: *"I think the threads don't need to use a global variable, either"* - [Confirmed](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVJLTsMwEJVY-hSzqw1plQSQUKRcgRW7qopC6qRGiR050wVCnIRNN3AoTsM4tsNnUbGbmffmvRl73j7GZzwYfTq9H7Fd331eFGoYjUXAg5X1XumOtdYMgGqQECGKfVWhtGhMP0XIylHWyNhetoByQi4KBtCYo8YMSkgp6XrzWPe-llOuqZ5VeZpWaepw16p0k_lWwo3uTRM7srnWGgsVsYIfvzdaJqBDx2J4RcrfinlU_DvBP_XyqOfYpOf4WzdpMqvv4BJufQNOtNN2ecHNwxxxrG0nsSSyCLq_vWvdSZ6lYsd-7FBGc_96ABPJIGXuF7hYxkcngVOcGDcz7xzhySgd8NEqjdw7JsEwgXb1Yincc-69YO3NBW2ayWtR3LzCMK0EY_6r_QmFS4oX9QU) that now. And not using a global one makes them much faster, as expected.

Comment: Correct, I modified my example to avoid using a global variable for the concurrent version. Timings are now almost on par.

Comment: Ok. I'd still use the same kind, but at least nonlocal is almost as fast as local, unlike global. (At least last I checked... There's a benchmark for "write_nonlocal" etc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#optimizations), but that's just for up to Python 3.9).

Comment: Thank you guys your advice is helpful for me and I learn a lots !!.
I really appreciate it !